# Create new variable if 2 of the 4 conditions are true using R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there any way to create a new variable `var5 = 1` if any 2 of the 4 conditions are TRUE

**Input:**

```
 id var1 var2 var3 var4
1   60   18  36.7  1000
2   30   23  45.6  4000
3   10   35  75.6  5000
4   50   35   53   3000

condition1: if var1<20 or var1>25
condition2: if var2>25
condition3: if var3>20 
condition4: if var4<1000 or var4>3000
```

Comment: @Li,  var5=1 if 2 of 4 conditions are true.

Comment: Yes, you can just use `if` with `sum`. As long as at least 2 elements are TRUE then you're good.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` which makes it cleaner to write this code:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% rowwise %>%
  mutate(var5 = ifelse(sum(c(var1 < 20 | var1 > 25, 
                             var2 > 25, 
                             var3 > 20, 
                             var4 < 1000 | var4 > 3000 )) >= 2,
                       1, 0))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
#Groups: <by row>
#
#     id  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
#  (int) (int) (int) (dbl) (int) (dbl)
#1     1    60    18  36.7  1000     1
#2     2    30    23  45.6  4000     1
#3     3    10    35  75.6  5000     1
#4     4    50    35  53.0  3000     1
```

You should change `>=` to `==` if you want exactly 2 conditions instead of at least 2 like I suppose you do.

Comment: Thanks for the help Molx

Comment: If one of the variable from var1-var4 contains NA values, the code does not work. Any solution to work with NA values?? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If your dataframe is `df`:

```
condition1 <- df$var1 < 20 | df$var1 > 25
condition2 <- df$var2 > 25
condition3 <- df$var3 > 20
condition4 <- df$var4 < 1000 | df$var4 > 3000

lgc <- condition1 + condition2 + condition2 + condition4

df$var5 <- ifelse(lgc %in% c(2,4), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Conditions 1 and 4 should use OR and not AND, otherwise they don't even make sense.

Comment: Yep you are right, I misread.